# How to resolve cross-domain issue with PDF.js?

Tags: apache, pdf.js

I am facing issue while making a cross-domain request to fetch PDF files through PDF.js. Can anybody give me a steps for enabling cross-domain request on Apache server for PDF.js?

Comment: A sample of your code will help...  
Also, as far as I know, cross-domain is more of a browser limitation than the plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Try queryString method of viewer.html; e.g www.example.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=yourFileURI

[Example Link](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://async5.org/moz/pdfjs.pdf)

NOTE: if clicking it doesn't work, try copy/pasting this into browser address bar: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http%3A%2F%2Fasync5.org%2Fmoz%2Fpdfjs.pdf
Ref: [A great reference on using viewer.html queryString parameters.](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website-%28Windows%29#opening-pdf-files-from-your-website)

A great guide to setup pdf.js can be found [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried link [http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf) but doesn't work. 

This means that this link doesn't support all cross-domain requests. I want a way to make PDF.js work with any cross domain PDF link.

Comment: @AnkurGupta you will need full [encoded URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), for this to work. Please do tell if encoding the url helps.